# DDD: Layer for reporting (View Model/Report Model)

Tags: c#, asp.net, domain-driven-design, viewmodel, layer

I have a Model and a Service for Reporting. It is very simple:

```
public class ReportService
{
    public Report Generate(){//}
}

public class Report
{
    string Title;   
    List<ReportField> Fields;
}

public class ReportField
{
    string FieldName;
    string FieldValue;  
}
```

The ouput looks like:

> ReportTitle
>
> Customer:     Foo
>   Amount:       50.5
>   Quantity:     100

My question is in which layer this belongs to? Is this a ViewModel? I output it to pdf, excel and bind it to grids. Is it good practice, that my application service returns this model?

Comment: If the main purpose of your application is report generation, this belongs to the "business" layer. However, if this is only part of a bigger application, it probably belongs to the "UI" layer. I don't usually encounter this problem, as I don't use layers; instead, I  have subsystems that talk to each other. For example, I would have a Reporting subsystem talking to a Database subsystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect your `Generate` method to contain business logic, so this belongs in your business layer. I would however expect the generate method to return a `Report` object and in your presentation layer, you can transform it from a `Report` to a PDF.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my question. So the whole code belongs into the Domain/Business Layer and not in my presentation layer? Right?

Comment: Business logic belongs in the business layer, presentation code in the presentation layer.